# Add class dynamically to values based on symbols

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-class

I wanted to add class dynamically if the integer is positive or negative..
I tried by calling a function from the HTML but that dosen't seem to be a right way.
Below is my plunker..

[Add class from html](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wqyb80w6z2b9NP9Qjibt?p=preview)

```
<div ng-repeat="i in test">
    <span class="test">  {{getValue(i)}} </span> 
</div>
```

I would like to know if there is any way wherin the signs(+/-) can be identified from the HTML and resolve them in the HTML itself..

Comment: Could you add some JS on the website in order to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) like follows :

```
// JS
$scope.isPositive = function(value) {
    return value.indexOf('-') == -1;
}
```

And

```
// HTML
<style>.green { color: green; } .red { color: red; }</style>
<!-- ... --> 
<span ng-class="isPositive(i) ? 'green' : 'red'">  {{getValue(i)}} </span>
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xPrlQDZA5ihcYwxto2wh?p=preview)

**EDIT**

To avoid use of the function, do the check in markup directly :

```
<span ng-class="i.indexOf('-') == -1 ? 'green' : 'red'">  {{getValue(i)}} </span>
```

[Updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xPrlQDZA5ihcYwxto2wh?p=preview)

Comment: Is there any way that I can use only HTML code and not any controller code.Because calling a function from HTML affects performance

Comment: I've added changes to handle it in the html. If you want upvote me, please wait tomorrow, I've earned the maximum reputation per day. Of course you can accept it now if you want.

Comment: Thanks chalasr..appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add like this in angular

```
ng-class="{'test': getValue(i) < 0}"

<span ng-class="{'test': getValue(i) < 0}">  {{getValue(i)}} </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add just one conditional in JS:

```
if( $("span").text().indexOf('+') != -1) {
    $("span").addClass("positiveClass");
}
```

See it in action on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeqwdc4j/)

Comment: Why use jQuery instead of angularJS (which the question is based on)  ? I use it as less as possible in my angular projects to keep a maximum of code in the primary technology of my application (as possible). Plus, the integrated jQlite (`angular.element`) provides all basic jQuery features, including the one you used in your answer.

Comment: I didn't saw the angular things on the question, neither plunker, but you're right.